# docker build produce corrupted python library installation

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

In numerous times, my `docker build` runs would result in corrupted python library installations. Sometimes, this would cause the docker build itself to just fail in the library installation step. But more severely, it could fail silently and one only sees the errors when running the application. The exact python library that is corrupted differs from build to build; re-installing the same version of the corrupted library would fix it. Using the `--no-cache` seems to be better but still happens even with this build option.

An example is shown below:

```
$ docker build --no-cache --force-rm --rm -f Dockerfile . -t mypy                           

$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash mypy                   
root:/# python
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 31 2018, 22:36:30)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm_api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 11, in <module>
    from statsmodels.datasets import webuse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/datasets/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import (anes96, cancer, committee, ccard, copper, cpunish, elnino,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/datasets/scotland/__init__.py", line 1
    6,�R��A�L
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

root:/# pip list | grep statsmodels
statsmodels            0.8.0

root:/# pip uninstall statsmodels

root:/# pip install statsmodels==0.8.0
Collecting statsmodels==0.8.0
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/e9/70d80b48c8c52a8de3ec7cd50e2aa2b1f3cf3f95e42b15fdcb59bd7189f3/statsmodels-0.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from statsmodels==0.8.0) (0.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from statsmodels==0.8.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from statsmodels==0.8.0) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->statsmodels==0.8.0) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->statsmodels==0.8.0) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas->statsmodels==0.8.0) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from patsy->statsmodels==0.8.0) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: statsmodels
Successfully installed statsmodels-0.8.0
root:/# python
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 31 2018, 22:36:30)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm_api
>>>
root:/#
```

and the Dockerfile is rather simple like:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
ARG app_dir=/root/myapp
ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key

RUN test -n "$aws_access_key_id" && test -n "$aws_secret_access_key"

RUN mkdir -p ${app_dir} /root/.aws

RUN echo "[default]" > /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id" >> /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_secret_access_key = $aws_secret_access_key" >> /root/.aws/credentials

ADD requirements.txt ${app_dir}/requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential libopenblas-dev gfortran procps less nano wget

RUN pip install -r ${app_dir}/requirements.txt
```

These silent errors are rather dangerous since we don't perform extensive validation using app-specific unit tests against docker images. We would want to see reproducible image builds. How to prevent these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but rather a suggestion.

Use multi-stage build if dependencies are only build dependencies and not runtime dependencies.

This way you produce wheels on the first step of build and you install the wheels on the second step. If created wheel is corrupted there's a chance that you won't be able to install them, I'm not sure though.

An example based on your Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim as builder

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential libopenblas-dev gfortran gcc gfortran g++  

RUN mkdir /wheels && \
    pip install -U pip wheel setuptools && pip wheel -r requirements.txt --wheel-dir=/wheels

FROM python3.6-slim as prod

ARG app_dir=/root/myapp
ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key

RUN echo "[default]" > /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id" >> /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_secret_access_key = $aws_secret_access_key" >> /root/.aws/credentials

COPY --from=builder /wheels /tmp/wheels
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheels/. -r requirements.txt 

WORKDIR $app_dir
```

If you don't mind about a longer build process, you could add a step between prod and builder, which would install and import all modules to test if import fail:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim as builder

ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential libopenblas-dev gfortran gcc gfortran g++  

RUN mkdir /wheels && \
    pip install -U pip wheel setuptools && pip wheel -r requirements.txt --wheel-dir=/wheels

FROM python3.6-slim as test

COPY --from=builder /wheels /tmp/wheels
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheels/. -r requirements.txt 
# Will fail if one of requirements cannot be imported
RUN python -c 'f = open("requirements.txt") ; modules = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()] ; f.close() ; list(map(__import__, modules))'

FROM python3.6-slim as prod

ARG app_dir=/root/myapp
ARG aws_access_key_id
ARG aws_secret_access_key

RUN echo "[default]" > /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_access_key_id = $aws_access_key_id" >> /root/.aws/credentials && \
  echo "aws_secret_access_key = $aws_secret_access_key" >> /root/.aws/credentials

COPY --from=builder /wheels /tmp/wheels
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/tmp/wheels/. -r requirements.txt 

WORKDIR $app_dir
```

This is quite an ugly proposal but maybe it can help you...